# How to get the middle element in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, element

How can we get the middle element in an array?

Example code:

```
string[] source = txtInput.Text.Split(',');
int[] nums = new int[input.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
} 

int first=nums[0];

int mid=///how is it?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
int mid = nums[nums.Length/2];
```

You take the size of the array (`nums.Length`), divide by two to get the index in the middle and use that index.

Comment: Take care when it comes to an uneven length, it is a matter of definition, what index you will choose to take.

Answer (score 4):

```
int mid = nums[nums.Length / 2];
```

Since it is all ints the number will be rounded down if Length is odd.

Answer (score 1):

mid = input.Lenght/2

Answer (score 1):

Get the middle index and then return the element at that middle index:

```
int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} 
int middIndex = arr.Length / 2;
Console.WriteLine(arr[middIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the total number of elements devided by 2 gives the middle element:

```
int mid = nums[Convert.ToInt32(num.Count /2)];
```

Comment: Integer division will always result in an integer - why are you using `Convert.ToInt32`? It is superfluous

Comment: Good point, I quickly typed it in and didn't realise at the spot. Indeed the Convert.ToInt32() is pointless